# Why xpath doing nothing?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[source code of login bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esZzp.png)

```
    BasicConfigurator.configure();
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Piotrek\\projekciki\\src\\main\\java\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://twitter.com/login?lang=pl");
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/form/div/div[1]/label/div/div[2]/div/input"));
    element.sendKeys("LOGIN");
```

just opening twitter and doing nothing.
where is the problem?

Comment: Since you're using an absolute path the input element in isolation is pointless (and brittle, but that's a separate issue). Why not find it by name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified code

```
BasicConfigurator.configure();   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Piotrek\\projekciki\\src\\main\\java\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.navigate("https://twitter.com/login?lang=pl");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);   
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[contains(@name,'username_or_email')]")));
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@name,'username_or_email')]"));
        element.sendKeys("LOGIN");
```

if above xpath doesn't work use this one-//input[contains(@name,'username_or_email' )and (@type='text')]

Comment: Suggestion: It might be helpful to the O.P. if you added some notes clarifying what you changed, why you changed it, and how that fixes the O.P.'s problem.